# A good way to store wood "outside"?

Tags: storage

I have a small shed at home that I attempt to do woodworking in. I need to make more room. I've seen lumber yards with outside storage.

Can I store some of my wood outside? Which wood?

For wood that is more sensitive to the elements, what is a good storage solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Keep your outside wood elevated, level and well supported. Place horizontal supports a maximum of 4' apart with at least 4" above the floor or ground.
- Allow for plenty of airflow placing 1/2" spacers between each layer of wood on the stack. Separate pieces on the same level by 1/2" as well.
- Keep them out of the weather. A shed is best, but a waterproof tarp will do as well, although it is best if the tarp does not directly contact the wood (again to allow airflow).
- Check your wood periodically to make sure it is keeping dry and is not being attacked by insects or other vermin.
- Finally remember to move your wood into the shop at least several weeks before you plan to use it so that it can acclimate to the shop.  You may want to invest in a moisture meter to check the dryness before you work with the material. If too wet, the wood may have to air dry for an extended period.

I am not sure what wood would qualify for special handling, but if you paid a lot for it or value it for special characteristics, keep it inside to be safe.

Comment: You are describing stickering wood: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/636/what-does-stickering-wood-mean

Comment: Any thoughts on the insects & vermin part. Can you clarify? Do you pre treat with a chemical or just check it frequently?

Comment: @Dano0430 There are several questions on th site addressing insect protection.  (Search the site in the bar above for insect protection).  If they don't help this may be a good question to ask on this site.